# Nested Ifelse statement in same table

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset below:

```
Col1     Col2    Spend
   A        0      100
   A        0      100
   B        0      100
   C        0      100
   D        0      200
```

I want to write an ifelse statement stating, if the sum of Col2 is greater than 0, then set Col2 = Spend. If the sum of Col2 is not greater than 0, then only apply the Spend Column to the corresponding rows where the value does not equal `A` and leave the rest as Col2 original values.

I want my final output to look like this:

```
Col1     Col2    Spend
   A        0      100
   A        0      100
   B      100      100
   C      100      100
   D      200      200
```

I think it would be something like this:

```
df$Col2 <- ifelse(sum(df$Col2)>0, df$Spend, ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2))
```

My issue is that when I run this, I check the sum again for Col2 and it still doesn't change. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try this: `if (sum(df$Col2)>0) df$Spend else ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2)`. Note that "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test..." and because `sum(df$Col2)>0` returns only one T or F then this will return one value, which is then replicated to fit in your dataframe's column. In other words, your `ifelse` returns one `0` and not five.

Comment: that worked thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The dataset**

```
df = read.table(text = "
Col1     Col2    Spend
A        0      100
A        0      100
B        0      100
C        0      100
D        0      200
", header=T)
```

**The problem**

If you run your code you'll see that it returns one `0` value, which is then replicated to fit the length of your column. This doesn't return five `0`s.

```
ifelse(sum(df$Col2)>0, df$Spend, ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2))

# [1] 0
```

This happens because you can see from `?ifelse` that "ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test..." and your (test) `sum(df$Col2)>0` will return only one value, becasue `sum(df$Col2)` is one value (i.e. the sum).

**The solution**

You can use an `if ... else` statement with a nested `ifelse` like this:

```
if (sum(df$Col2)>0) df$Spend else ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2)

# [1]   0   0 100 100 200
```

So, you check that if (your test) `sum(df$Col2)>0` is true, then return the whole `Spend` column, otherwise continue to the `ifelse` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has to do with how R handles vectorized operations, since the first argument to your `ifelse` statement returns a logical of length 1 (since `sum(df$Col2) > 0` can only return `True`, `False` or `NA`), only one of the values is being used in the others.

Here would be an example of what is going on

```
> ifelse(TRUE, 1:4, 1:4)
[1] 1
> ifelse(c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 1:4, 1:4)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

So your example would be fixed by changing the syntax as such

```
if (sum(df$Col2)>0) {
    df$Col2 <- df$Spend
} else {
    df$Col2 <- ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2)
}
```

And if you REALLY WANT a one-liner

```
df$Col2 <- ifelse(rep(sum(df$Col2)>0, nrow(df)), df$Spend, ifelse(df$Col1!="A", df$Spend, df$Col2))
```